# Xcode 12.2 Building for iOS, but the linked library 'libXQP2P_API_IOS.a' was built for macOS

Tags: ios

xcode 12.2 Real machine compilation error
Excluded Architectures > "arm64" invalid, and Modify VALID_ARCHS value without effect

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. SO is for specific coding issues only. Its not for support with Software or Hardware issues.

Comment: Xcode 12 compile error after updater： Building for iOS, but the linked library was built for macOS.It's not a software or hardware problem.Have you ever had the same problem? How to solve this problem?